# Heroku doesn't print whole line of data when imported from external spreadsheet

Tags: python, heroku, gitpod

I've just deployed my project to Heroku as per the requirments from my institute.  I was going through it ensuring everything works as it should do and came across a very big issue.

When I call on my spreadsheet for data and print it to the terminal 8 columns of data should be printed with values below the titles.  On Heroku it does this for 4 out of the 8 columns.

Now on GitPod it will print the whole line but on Heroku it doesn't want to do that at all.  I suspect this has something to do with Python's limit of 80 characters per line, but as I'm not writing it myself this shouldn't apply.

I'm really in a bad spot as this is due tomorrow and need to come up with a solution today.  I've got no idea if anyone has experienced similar before but my research has given no results.

If anybody has any suggestions then that would be amazing and greatly appreciated.

Screenshot showing example of issue:
[image: Heroku terminal vs GitPod terminal]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: "Python's limit of 80 characters per line"—Python has no such limit. 80 characters is a common width for terminals (less common these days), but Python doesn't limit this.

Comment: Your school is asking you to deploy to Heroku... so they can read output from your logs? That doesn't make a lot of sense. How do they intend to read the logs?

Comment: Is that a pandas dataframe? Please always include the [tag:pandas] tag when asking questions about pandas data structures, as described in the [tag:python] tag wiki: "When using a Python variant (e.g. Jython, PyPy) or library (e.g. Pandas, NumPy), please include it in the tags."

Comment: Hey @Chris, I'm not sure about your comment on logs I'll be honest.  I've found my solution within the project template I'm given so I can deploy it to a live site through Heroku.  I adjusted the JS files to be at 80 col to 160 col so it will allow my imported data.  Thankfully a simple fix but also hidden a little bit within the repo.  Thirdly, yes it's the pandas dataframe. I honestly didn't think of listing it as a tag, apologies

Comment: "I adjusted the JS files"—what JS files? You haven't said anything about JavaScript, or a web interface at all. That's why I asked about reading your logs—the screenshots you shared look like what might get printed to the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my solution within the project template I'm given so I can deploy it to a live site through Heroku. I adjusted the JS files to be at 80 col to 160 col so it will allow my imported data.  Could've been resolved without coming to here